# Does diverging attitudes towards Slovenia coincide with Trump's election?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump, public-opinion

[Which Country Is America’s Strongest Ally? For Republicans, It’s Australia](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2017/02/03/upshot/which-country-do-americans-like-most-for-republicans-its-australia.html?action=click&contentCollection=The%20Upshot&region=Footer&module=WhatsNext&version=WhatsNext&contentID=WhatsNext&moduleDetail=undefined&pgtype=Multimedia) mentions that Slovenia is one of the countries which Republicans most favourably view compared to Democrats.

I can understand most of the other countries where there's a difference, such as Australia, Israel, Russia, Zimbabwe, Cuba, and the Palestinian Territories.

I checked whether there was possibly a generalised divergence in Eastern European countries, just like there was for Russia, but I couldn't spot it. Instead, the only hypothesis I have is that it's to do with the wife of Republican president Donald Trump being from Slovenia.

Has divergence in views on Slovenia coincided with Trump's rise to power, and if so, is it Republicans, Democrats, or both who have changed their opinion on Slovenia? Are there any other explanations for the divergence in views?

Comment: Reminds me of George W Bush making a confusion during his 2000 campaign between Slovenia and Slovakia. Maybe some Republicans still don't really know where Slovenia is? Anyway, I think you pointed out the single explanation: the only thing that comes to their minds when someone evocates Slovenia is Melania Trump.

Comment: [Looking at the numbers](https://today.yougov.com/news/2017/02/02/americas-friends-and-enemies/), it somewhat boggles the mind that only two countries (Canada and the UK) are US allies in the mind of a majority of US citizens...

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy - how is that surprising? Most other nominally-allied counties rarely appear to act as true allies majority of the time, frequently seeming to be undermining US interests (as random example, witness France sabotaging anti-Saddam sanctions, or Germany being in energy bed with Putin's Russia). Citizens tend to notice that (especially the large halfjority that are not Europhile progressives). Add on constant barrage of their citizens and media dumping on USA, which also doesn't help the **perception**.

Comment: @user4012: It's surprising because it gives the impression that the US public either doesn't trust its 35 or so allies or only has a vague idea of who they actually are. (The numbers arguably do suggest that the public considers _most_ of their allies under "friendly" or "ally" more than "not friendly" or (at times) "enemy.") Also, allies are not lapdogs; this means occasionally begging to differ about things like WMDs being present in Iraq, needing to heat oneself during winters, or worrying about aggressive rhetoric between nuclear weapon equipped blowhards.

Comment: The explanation you suggest is reasonable. I don't think you can get proof. All you will get is further opinions.

Answer (score 2):

**The NYT charts and numbers misrepresent the data.**

[Looking at the numbers](https://today.yougov.com/news/2017/02/02/americas-friends-and-enemies/) on YouGov, Slovenia rates as 2% enemy, 8% not friendly, 40% friendly, 5% ally, and 45% not sure across all respondents.

They asked 7,150 respondents for their opinion, but asked each one about a random selection of 15 of 144 countries. If you make the numbers show in the table where you can select of a few individual countries and the breakdown by respondent type, you can see this translates to roughly 1,000-1,400 respondents per country in total. If you ignore the 45% not sure replies (which the NYT seems to have done), you end up with a relatively small sample size and I'd wager nothing conclusively different.

Making things worse, the NYT team massaged the numbers to create their article. Notice that the cited survey groups response in terms of "Enemy," "Not Friendly," "Friendly," "Ally," and "Not Sure." The NYT's team took these raw numbers, produced a friendliness ranking prey tell how (possibly `positive - negative`), and then relabeled the ally/enemy scale based on not on the actual friendliness figure, but rather on how close to either end of the scale the countries were.

Zimbabwe for instance sits at 4% enemy, 16% not friendly, 32% friendly, 4% ally, and 40% not sure. That puts it firmly in don't care/don't know territory, with somewhat friendly tendencies, yet the NYT somehow conjures up a stark contrast between how democrats would think it's friendly and how republicans would think it's not. This make it very tempting to file under garbage in, garbage out.

Comment: The numbers you refer to don't describe the changes between 2014 and 2017. Do you have a link to the 2014 numbers?

Comment: 2014 because the nytimes article descibes the changes over three years. And the OP asks about how the views on Slovenia have changed. The OP also asks about differences between Democrats and Republicans. But the yougov page doesn't have this information. So the nytimes must have another source of data. To answer the question you need to discuss not only what the perception of Slovenia is, but also how it has changed.

Comment: @JamesK: I see. The NYT numbers were such garbage (aside: it really pains me to say so because f@&k what a disappointment) that I didn't read the full article. They don't seem to provide immediate sources for the 2014 data (a double whammy).